# Files duplicated after manually renaming

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Using Intellij, Springboot.

When I rename the files in a directory manually(Intellij->refactor->rename) and restart my web application, when I walk in that directory I can see the renamed files are duplicated (there now is both old name and new name in my app)
What am I missing?!

my directory is under /resources/my_dir

```
File myDirectory = new ClassPathResource(MY_DIR).getFile();
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(queryDirectory.toPath())) {
        paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(path -> setFile(path));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume here, that you are talking about files in the directory of compiled files. The reason is that only the source files are renamed when renaming something like an XML file in the resources folder, or whatever the case may be.

That, however is not in any way tied to the `target` directory. Build tools, like maven, or I assume the compiler intellij uses copies everything it can't compile to that `target` directory.

What you have to do is clean the project and build again, so that the target directory is "clean"